# svg icons are not showing properly in different screen sizes or dimention android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio, svg

Using svg icon in drawable folder and creating dimen.xml files in values hdpi,xdhpi,xxhpi,xxxhpi folders but svg icons are showing differently in different dimension devices or svg icon getting a bit different layout like hdpi,xdhpi,xxhpi,xxxhpi. So is there any solution for this problem.

[image]
[image]

**SVG content**

```
<vector 
  android:height="24dp" 
  android:viewportHeight="96.0" 
  android:viewportWidth="96.0"
  android:width="24dp" 
  xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">; 
        <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M32.74,87A23.74,23.74 0,1 0,9 63.26,23.74 23.74,0 0,0 32.74,87ZM63.26,87A23.74,23.74 0,1 0,39.52 63.26,23.74 23.74,0 0,0 63.26,87ZM48,56.48A23.74,23.74 0,1 0,24.26 32.74,23.74 23.74,0 0,0 48,56.48Z" 
        android:strokeColor="#141515" 
        android:strokeWidth="4"/> 
  </vector>
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to explain the situation more? Why are you using the same VectorDrawable in different drawable folders? Normally there would only be one copy of the VectorDrawable. How does your dimens.xml relate to the question; what values are affected by the dimens.xml and where are they used?

Comment: understand ur point @Lewis, edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a common mistake when we add SVG

Make sure you are checking the Override as you can see in the image:

[image]

Hope this helps.